# DHCP Issue Installing Linux Distros

Tags: linux, system-installation, dhcp

I am trying to install various distros of Linux with all of them having the same problem. When it comes to the network basically it cannot connect. I am connected via ethernet cable to a router. When I am in the installation process of a distro it says that it is having a DHCP issue and whether or not if i want to set up one manually or ignore it. I was trying to install some distros via network like Fedora and opensuse so I was not able to complete the installation. I am not sure if it is a router setting problem or a hardware issue. I am using a ThinkPad T420.

edit:Not sure about about the othe dhcp services as I am not that knowledgeable about networks. My phone and other laptop is connected to the internet via WiFi. My desktop PC connects to the router no problem. There are four ports on the router.

edit: so I noticed that it does not work on laptops. It works on my Desktop PC but on laptops for some reason it cannot find any problems with windows network trouble shooter. Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: Does your router or anything else provide DHCP services?  Do you have any other computers connected to that network and can they successfully DHCP?  Do you have multiple ethernet ports and it's trying to use one different from where the wire is connected?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your device is having a conflict with another. Is there any device which uses static IP address in same range as your routers dhcp.? Do you have any other devices on network which get IP address from router dhcp. If so check and verify none of the other devices are having same IP address or having problems with obtaining IP address from said router. Could be your lease scope is also out of available IP to hand out.